# google analytics for wordpress

Tags: google-analytics

I have a problem in Google Analytics and I don't know what is missing in it. I added the script file to my WordPress website header like this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

 (function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async =   true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
 })();

</script>
```

When I opened the Google Analytics I saw *Tracking Installed* but when I open the dashboard to see the reports and my information everything shows 0 people visited this site, 0 visits, everything is zero and I don't know why ?

Comment: of course i did that i wrote in my question that the code is just like that not this one and it said track installed that is not the problem

Comment: Sarah, please use upper- lowercase letters when writing questions. Questions are for later readers as well and should be easy to read. Thank you.

Comment: Google Analytics is not real-time tracking service, so if it shows tracking installed you have to wait several hours to see any changes.

Comment: its working thaks everyone you were right it works after 24 hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default Google Analytics reports show historical data compiled over the course of the last 24-48 hours (generally, you will not see anything reported with standard reports until at least 24 hours have passed; the greater and the more geographically-dispersed your traffic is, the longer it can take to compile all traffic data).

Switch to [Real-Time Reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1638635&topic=1638563&rd=1) to test in real-time.

Answer (score 1):

sarah, check the time frame (at the top of your GA) for which dates you are view your report. By default, GA does not include the current day ... you need to change the same.

Answer (score 0):

If Google Analytics mentionned that your tracking has been installed, you can be assured that you did it right. You generally have to wait (the next day if I'm not mistaken) before you get tracking information.

Comment: you may check right now if it works, just go to Real-time Tracking and see what happens when you surf your website in another tab/window.